# Error when using multiprocessing with Pandas: 'Can't pickle <class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>: attribute lookup Pandas on pandas.core.frame failed

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, pickle, python-multiprocessing, execution-time

I am generating a script to validate XMLs (the specific code for each validation rule is written in the *validation_rules* module) and the code execution time was getting too long.  So, I decided to use the *multiprocessing* module to process the DataFrame in parallel. However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

*_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>: attribute lookup Pandas on pandas.core.frame failed*

This is the code I've tried:

```
def validate_xml(df_results):
    # Create a Pool of processes
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    # Map the function to the rows in parallel
    result_list = pool.map(apply_validation_function (df_results.itertuples(index=False), df_results))
    # Combine the results into a dataframe
    df_results[['status', 'comments']] = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
    return df_results

def apply_validation_function(row, df_results):
    function_name = str(row['function'])
    if isinstance(function_name, str) and function_name != 'nan':
        try:
            function = getattr(validation_rules, function_name)
            result = function(df_results, row.name)
            return pd.Series({'status': result[0], 'comments': result[1]})
        except Exception as e:
            return pd.Series({'status': 'Error', 'comments': f'Error: {e}'})
    else:
        return pd.Series({'status': '', 'comments': ''})
```

Before the validation, df_results has the following columns:

- line_idx
- line_text
- rule_id
- rule_tag_id
- function   (the name of the function in the module *validation_rules*)

And after the validation, the previous ones plus:

- status
- comments

Comment: Why do you pass `df_results` to `apply_validation_function`?

Comment: Because all validation functions that are in the "validation_rules" module receive as parameters the complete dataframe (df_results) and the xml line index. And the reason why it is necessary to pass the dataframe is because the validation of a line can depend on values in other lines, so a validation function must be able to "see" the rest of the lines of the dataframe

Comment: The error message is telling you that a Pandas dataframe cannot be pickled.  Pickling is required for transferring data between Python processes.  Pandas thought of that, and there is a method to convert a dataframe to a picklable form: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html